# PostAsync Json C#

Tags: c#, json, post

Tenho a Seguinte classe definida:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public string name
    public string content
    public int itilcategories_id
}
```

E a seguinte amostra de código:

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://stgsd.primaverabss.com/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 ticket.name = "TESTE";
 ticket.content = "teste";
 ticket.itilcategories_id = 1

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("apirest.php/Ticket/", XXXXXXXXX );
```

O meu objetivo é substituir os XXXXXXX que estão no PostAsync de forma a que no seu lugar passe a informação do Ticket e que ao enviar para o respectivo link o conteúdo seja o seguinte:

```
{"input":[{"name": "TESTE", "content": "teste", "itilcategories_id":"1"}]}
```

Alguma ideia? Qualquer dúvida avisem!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Para reproduzir o modelo apresentado, você precisa criar um objeto que possui um atributo chamado input e que este receba um array ou lista de Tickets. Depois você precisa serializar esse objeto em um json e passar ele como um `StringContent()` (adicionando os headers necessários) para o seu método `PostAsync()`.

Segue um exemplo:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://stgsd.primaverabss.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

var ticket = new Ticket();
ticket.name = "TESTE";
ticket.content = "teste";
ticket.itilcategories_id = 1;

List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>();
tickets.Add(ticket);

var parametro = new
{
    input = tickets.ToArray()
};            

var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parametro); 
var contentString = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
contentString.Headers.ContentType = new 
MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); 
contentString.Headers.Add("Session-Token", session_token); 


HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync("apirest.php/Ticket/", contentString);
```

Comment: inclua a declaração do seu client

Comment: @idkWhy, Ajustado.

Comment: @IdkWhy, resolveu?

Comment: Dá erro 400: Bad Request

Comment: Você tem certeza que aquele é o modelo esperado? via postman, você consegue realizar a operação?

Comment: Utilizo fiddler e sim realizei a operação

Comment: Acabei de fazer um e deu certinho

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75136/discussion-between-leandro-angelo-and-idkwhy).

Comment: Passar "application/json"  no construtor do StringContent e em seguida contentString.Headers.ContentType = new 
MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"); e redundandia, nao?

Comment: @Aitiow sim e é proposital, já aconteceu em algumas aplicações, da variável não ser adicionada quando apresentada no construtor do `StringContent()`. Então por hábito eu sempre reforço o MediaType também